# constructor functions inside an object?

Tags: javascript, constructor, encapsulation

I was working on creating a bunch of objects within an object and I thought it would be a good idea to put a constructor as an object property to encapsulate everything a bit further for example.

```
//surprisingly you can't do this it returns an error
// Uncaught TypeError: this.Dogs is not a constructor
 let dogs={
      keagon: new this.Dog("keagon","shih sue"),
      spike: new this.Dog("spike","lab"),
      Dog: function(name,breed){
         this.name=name;
        this.breed=breed;       
    }
 }

//nor can you do this

 let dogs2={
      keagon: new dogs2.Dog("keagon","shih sue"),
      spike: new dogs2.Dog("spike","lab"),
      Dog: function(name,breed){
         this.name=name;
        this.breed=breed;       
    }
 }
// this again returns an error
//Uncaught ReferenceError: dogs2 is not defined
//this leads me to believe you cant access objects within themselves       
//without the this key word correct? If so, I find a that a bit surprising
//because you can call functions within themselves.

//I was able to encapsulate like I wanted, by storing the newly created 
//objects as properties of their constructor, for example

function Dog(name,breed){
      this.name=name;
      this.breed=breed;
}
Dog.dogs={
          keagon: new Dog("keagon","shih sue"),
          spike: new Dog("spike","lab")
         }
  // Dog.dogs.keagon > outputs Dog {name: "keagon", breed: "shih sue"}
  //keagon object is a object type of object and not of function so it also
  //inherits all the Object methods
```

So is there a way to put put constructors and object properties if not is there a reason you can't put constructors in objects, but you can store objects on their constructors and is doing this a bad idea? Would creating objects and storing them on their constructor to encapsulate them be bad practice? Are there any problems that can occur that I'm not aware of?

Comment: this in the first exemple reference the window object because the object is being made i think. The second one is referencing an object that is not created yet, so it won't work

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't declare a variable and use it in itself on his construction.
You can do like this

```
let dogs2={
      Dog: function(name,breed){
         this.name=name;
        this.breed=breed;       
    }
 }
```

And

```
dogs2.keagon= new dogs2.Dog("keagon","shih sue");
dogs2.spike= new dogs2.Dog("spike","lab");
```

This way you'll get the result you wanted.